# ¿Por que no puedo ejecutar mi app despues de un flutter upgrade?

Tags: flutter

recibí la notificación sobre una actualización de **Flutter**, por lo tanto ejecute `flutter upgrade`.
por lo que intente ejecutar ahora mi app con **Visual studio code**.

Me manda los siguientes mensaje de error que no se como solucionar.

```
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_image-2.0.0/lib/network.dart:73:24: Error: The method 'NetworkImageWithRetry.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.   ImageStreamCompleter load(NetworkImageWithRetry key) {
                       ^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').   ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^ /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-1.1.3/lib/src/cached_network_image_provider.dart:42:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.   ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').   ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);

/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_map-0.7.3/lib/src/layer/tile_provider/mbtiles_image_provider.dart:90:24: Error: The method 'MBTileImage.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.   ImageStreamCompleter load(MBTileImage key) {
                       ^ /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').   ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto debido a que hubo breaking changes en el sdk de Flutter, por lo tanto esas dependencias tienen que actualizarse, veo que tienes 2 dependencias que te marca error, solo actualizas:

Para `flutter_image` debes usar `3.0.0` y para `flutter_map` aún no publican la nueva versión pero puedes apuntar directamente al repositorio:

```
  flutter_map:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/avioli/flutter_map.git
      ref: 0.8.0
```

No te olvides de `flutter clean`

Comment: Como actualizo `flutter_image` si no lo tengo agregado en mi **pubspec.yaml**, `flutter_map` si lo ubico ya que yo fui quien lo instalo. pero el otro no lo encuentro

Comment: Entonces solo basta con flutter_map

Comment: Ok.. entonces tengo que esperar a que se realice una nueva actualización de `flutter_map` para que funcione mi app  ?

Comment: En mi respuesta puse como debes incluirla en tu pubspec por ahora, deberia funcionar con eso

Comment: Gracias ya que soy nuevo en esto y no se de donde sacar la url de git para colocarla en el **.yaml**  basándome en tu respuesta, encontre los datos a colocar [aqui](https://github.com/johnpryan/flutter_map/issues/473#issuecomment-565716005)

Comment: Pero me salen muchas notas en rojo al ejecutar, ¿Ameritan otra pregunta? o ¿no afectan a mi app ahora  ni a futuro?

Comment: si la app no te compila, pues afecta, pero si solo son warning , lee bien de que son y bueno verifica que no afecte nada